# Heroku How do I migrate from expeditedssl to heroku ssl

Tags: ssl, heroku

I have used ExpeditedSSL for some time and want to move to the free Heroku SSL.  The [instructions for migrating from SSL Endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#migrate-from-ssl-endpoint-to-heroku-ssl) say to run

```
heroku certs:add example.crt example.key --type sni
```

But how do I find out which files I might have used originally?  Or did ExpeditedSSL generate them for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or, does it matter if I use the same certificates?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the process on how to migrate? Reading through the documentation its hard to figure out what to do w/o having some downtime.